# How to display attached images on single.php file in wordpress

Tags: custom-wordpress-pages

Maybe someone solved this problem sorry if I am asking again this question. I have one post displaying on front page now this post has one feature Image along with other images and gallery.

What I want when user click on post so it will go on single.php to show full post view. I want to display on this single.php view an image and some text as well as a custom gallery images but not the feature image.

how can I achieve this I wrote one code but it did not work.

```
function displayPostImages() { 

global $post; function

$attachments = get_children(array('post_parent' => $post->ID, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'menu_order', 'post_type' => 'attachment', 'post_mime_type' => 'image' ));



$image =  get_post_thumbnail_id( $post->ID); // featured_image ID
$featured_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($image);

if ($attachments) { // if there are images attached to posting, start the flexslider markup
    foreach ( $attachments as $attachment_id => $attachment ) { 

    if($attachment->ID != $image && $featured_image ){

    $img_source = wp_get_attachment_image_src( $attachment_id, 'full' )[0];

    //print_r($img_source);
?>

// here will be HTML to display TOP images text and gallery images.





<?php
             }
         }
     }
 }
displayPostImages();
?>
```

Comment: https://github.com/fxstar/Wordpress-phonex/blob/master/single-gallery.php see here is working template exampl

Comment: Thanks Breakermind. I tried that script but it does not do what I am looking for script pull again the featured image and gallery script has error.

Answer (score 0):

and what is returned your function?
I don`t see "return" or "echo $someresult";

empty or not this array $attachments = get_children....